# section: newpage instead of line stretching

Tags: sectioning, xetex

I have a lot of sections containing sometimes not much more than one or two lines. It's an edition of letters and i have no problem if a page is not filled to the last line. LaTeX tries to stretch the sections to the end of the page, giving the hole layout an uneven feeling. How can I set the penalties so that the processor prefers ending a page and starting a new one instead of stretching the lines between paragraphs?

Comment: Use the directive `\raggedbottom` in your preamble. The default is `\flushbottom`.

Comment: This produces a better output indeed. But it still stretches the paragraphs. Is it possible to turn of the stretching all together?

Comment: It shouldn't stretch the paragraphs, but maybe it stretches some rubber lengths. Can you post a small example demonstrating the problem?

Comment: I tried to produce a MWE but found the error along the way. I use reledmac and I usually had a paragraph with a date set like this: \begin{flushright}\pstart blablabla \pend\end{flushright} this would produce an empty space afterwards which would be stretched or – sometimes not. I now changed it all to \pstart\begin{flushright} … and everything works as desired after writing \raggedbottom into the header.

Comment: That's fine! A number of problems can solved by just trying to produce a short example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for the command \raggedbottom, as [Bernard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38908/bernard) mentionned in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\newpage` before starting a new section.

As an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\section{sec1}
test

\newpage

\section{sec2}
test


\end{document}
```

Comment: This I know, but I don't want to do all the page-breaking myself. Bernards answer with \raggedbottom did the trick.